# 2 buttons having the same functionality in iphone application

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am creating an application with call functionality, I want to have the phone image on the right hand side and the name of the contact on the left hand side. Currently this has been implemented by placing the 2 buttons side by side, hence if the user clicks on any of the buttons, the same functionality (calling the contact) happens.

Is this allowed according to Apple HIG? Please let me know.

Thank You,
Ashvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think anything in the HIG specifically disallows this, but it seems like a bad idea, for a couple of reasons:

1. If there are two buttons side-by-side, users will assume the buttons do different things, and will be confused when they don't.
2. It wastes screen real-estate that could probably be put to better use.

From your description it is hard to tell exactly what this looks like, but it sounds like something that needs to be re-designed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I just wanted to confirm before I designed the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Overlapping buttons?

- It might not give you an intuitive UI, as the content of the overlapped button might get truncated by the overlapping button.
- As Kristopher has explained, it will result in a bad user experience.
- It is possible, that your app might get rejected because of the truncations as the user will not be readily able to perceive the content.
- If look of the button is what you are concerned about, then you can just set one image (whether odd shaped or not) to one button, as long as the user is able to perceive that it is a button.
- In the odd shaped image, you should also ensure that the functionality does not get triggered when the user touches the transparent area of the image, otherwise it might confuse the user.

Hope these points help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any mention about overlapping the buttons? Suppose for better design/look and feel, I have to place two buttons which partially overlaps each other, is it disallowed? Still the screen looks good and there will not be any confusion about the buttons. But only point is they are two different buttons, which assumes same functionality and has overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some more information on the about query.
The buttons are overlapping as one is just a graphics and another is a rounded rectangle button whose Title changes dynamically.

If they can not be overlapped, can we have an odd shape button on the screen as long as user feels that they are buttons?

Thanks.